# How to convert a git repo to an hg repo

Tags: git, mercurial

I want to convert a git repository to a mercurial one.

I try first to do:

```
hg clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
```

but the command was aborted and the reason is that the link does not appear to be an `hg` repository.

Instead of that I used git clone...

But I need `.hg` and not `.git` because after that I will need to apply `hg` commands...

So, how can I proceed to convert this `.git`? I read about `hg convert` but I didn't understand the manner to use it. I would appreciate any help!

Regards,

Belhadj

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer seems to only work with a local repository; you need to clone the repository with `git` before using it, then run `hg convert` on the cloned `git` repository to get a Mercurial one.

Neither version control system can read the other’s repositories by themselves, because they use different formats. There are a bunch of tools for conversion between them; one of them, [Mercurial’s Convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension), comes bundled with Mercurial and might be the easiest to use.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you give me an example using this convert extension?

Comment: I am not; apparently that’s what I get for trusting the documentation. I have not been able to try anything that doesn’t just have it say <whatever> `does not look like a Git repository`. Everybody recommends the third-party extension [Hg-Git](http://hg-git.github.io/); once you install that your proposed command line works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the convert extension.  You didn't mention operating system:

1. If using TortoiseHg, go to `File, Settings, Extensions` and turn on `convert`.  Skip to Step 4.
2. Otherwise, edit the Mercurial config file:
   (Windows) Mercurial.ini
   (Linux)   .hgrc
3. Add the following section to enable the extension.

   ```
   [extensions]
   convert =
   ```
4. Run `hg convert <path_to_git_repo> <path_to_desired_hg_repo>`

Also note the `hggit` extension, if enabled, can clone from a git repository to a local Mercurial repository.  You can work in Mercurial, then push back to the git repository.  Your command example should work with `hggit` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with Git repo from Mercurial, may I suggest you use [Hg Git Plugin](http://hg-git.github.io/). There's a documentation but in short  - you just clone that repo, then point you `~/.hgrc` to it via

```
[extensions]
hggit = ~/.hg-ext/hg-git/hggit
```

And then you can clone git repositories using `hg`.

```
hg clone git://github.com/schacon/some-repo.git
```

Of course you can clone using `https` or locally too.